# Not able to find the ip address

Tags: ip-address, ping

I am trying to find the static ip address of `google.com` in cmd prompt with the use of ping command as `ping google.com`. Instead of showing me the ip address of google, it is giving the following output. Not able to find the google ip address. So, instead of showing the ip address for google.com it is providing `2404:6800:4009:82b::200e`. Not able to figure out how to find the ip address. Please help

[image: Output]

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

Comment: Is that an ipv6 address? Are you using Ping6? Check the options to get ipv4. What OS and terminal are you using. Please copy your commande and output and put then in your question.

Comment: @Kendle, in many OSes, ping works for both IPv4 and IPv6. For example, it does in Windows, but you can pick a specific IP by using `-4` or `-6` options. IOS uses the `ip` or `ipv6` options to pick a specific IP.

Answer (score 2):

This is the IPv6, if you want the IPv4 you need to run

```
ping google.com -4
```